# How to access the firestore database on every device in c#

Tags: c#, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uno-platform

So I have been stuck with this issue for a long time now and I can't figure it out.

I am trying to connect my C# application to the firestore database with the following code:

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"JSONfileName.json";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", path);
firestoreDb = FirestoreDb.Create("DataBaseID");
```

This works just fine on a desktop but once I try this on a Android device it raises an error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Message=Error reading credential file from location JSONfileName.json: Could not find file 
"/JSONfileName.json"
```

I have also created an environment variable that points to this JSONfileName.json. And the JSONfileName is inside the project.

But it still raises an error on other devices. Except on desktop.

**Question:**

What is the proper way to access the firestore database on every device ? (UWP/Android/ios/.....)

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**

Here is the new connection code:

```
var currentPath = string.Empty;
#if __ANDROID__
        currentPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"JSONfileName.json";
 #endif
 #if WINDOWS_UWP
        currentPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"JSONfileName.json";
        
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", 
 currentPath);
#endif

        //string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory ;


        firestoreDb = FirestoreDb.Create("DataBaseID");
```

Also added that in NameSapce.Droid.csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
 <PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Firestore" Version="1.1.0-beta01" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

Now the program doesn't crash but I still can't access the firestore database.

here the new error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Application Default Credentials 
are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute 
Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable 
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file 
defining the credentials. See 
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default- 
credentials for more information.'
```

Comment: The error message indicates that the JSONfileName.json cannot be found. The `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` that you use to build the path probably refers to your development machine, which doesn't exist in the applicaton executable. I recommend searching for how to bundle a file into your application binary, or how to access it at a relative path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At first I was thinking like you. But turn out, the program was crashing because I have forgot some code. Now the problem is that I still can't access the firestore database. I will update the post for more clarity. Thanks again.